# "Save as" page with custom content

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm opening a new window with `var newWindow = window.open();` and passing new content to it with `newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = htmlString;`

I want to "Save As" the page as .html, but the option appears to be disabled. I'm currently using Chrome.

I tried `window.open("file_that_doesnt_exist.html")` and passing content to it, and it works, but I don't want to show the full url of the page.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is a fiddle if someone wants to try both examples:
https://jsfiddle.net/jc7fsh8L/1/

Comment: Maybe try using `document.close()`?

Comment: @Feathercrown I tried what you said but the problem persists.

Comment: `window.open("hello.html")` won't work in IE

Comment: Huh... have you looked at the documentation(s) of any and all relevant parts?

Comment: @kodecount Frankly, I think we should just stop caring about IE.

Comment: @kodecount the example with `window.open()` works in IE 9 and up, and I agree with @Feathercrown that we should stop caring about IE.

Comment: @Feathercrown I spent the past day trying to solve this and reading all I could about the subject but to no avail, that's why I ended up asking about this here.

Comment: Well, I appreciate the research! I'm not sure how much I can help here, though-- if you've already done the research, then I have no more suggestions, as this is a little out of my scope.